# Cash register and the amount of change returned

Tags: java

Write a method that will simulate a change machine found at cash registers. 
The cost and amount paid will be passed to the method.

Tell the user how much change is owed and number of quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies in change a customer would receive. 
Pay special attention to roundoff errors (see comments in starter code).

Your program should use division and modular division. No if’s or loops may be used. You may assume all change will be between $0 and $.99 Hint: Modular division is a great way to find the remainder of a division. Think about how you can use this to calculate the change that is left over after some coins are given.

```
Sample Run: 
Cost of the Item: 4.57 
Amount Paid: 5.00

Change Owed: 0.43 
Quarters: 1 
Dimes: 1 
Nickels: 1 
Pennies: 3
```

My code

```
int quarters; int dimes; int nickels; int pennies;

changes = changes * 100; 

int change1 = (int)changes; 

quarters = change1 / 25; 
change1 = change1 % 25;

dimes = change1 / 10;
change1 = change1 % 10;

nickels = change1 / 5;
change1 = change1 % 5;

pennies = change1 / 1;
change1 = change1 % 1;

String a = "Coins left in cash register:";
System.out.println(a 
    + "\n\nQuarters: " + quarters
    + "\nDimes: " + dimes 
    + "\nNickels: " + nickels 
    + "\nPennies: " + pennies 
    + "");
```

How would I fix this? I need help in declaring the method `ChangeDue` and returning instead of printing.

Comment: You could create class called `Change` which is constructed by passing in the raw amount and converts to quarters etc.  The method `ChangeDue` would return an instance of this class

Comment: Why do you believe you need to be *"returning instead of printing"*? The instructions says to *"Tell the user"*, which you do by printing the instructions. Which means the method doesn't return anything. --- You do need to create a method where *"the cost and amount paid will be passed to the method"*. You have learned about parameters, right? It's a method with 2 parameters, named e.g. `cost` and `amountPaid`.